# Class constructor ForceUpdateApp cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and getting the below error.

**ForceUpdateApp.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class ForceUpdateApp extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.forceUpdateHandler = this.forceUpdateHandler.bind(this);
    };

    forceUpdateHandler() {
        this.forceUpdate();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.forceUpdateHandler}>Force Update</button>
                <p>Random Number: {Math.random()}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ForceUpdateApp();
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ForceUpdateApp from './ComponentAPI/ForceUpdateApp.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ForceUpdateApp />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

But, I am getting the below error. I tried other answers available, but unable to find a fix. Kindly guide me how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's not how creating an instance of the class works. You need to use `new` if you want to create an instance.

That being said, you don't need to create an instance in your case. Just write `export default ForceUpdateApp;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the constructor when exporting.

`export default ForceUpdateApp()` should be `export default ForceUpdateApp`